# How to limit number of searches per user in PHP

Tags: php, search

I am trying to develop an application where a guest user can see search results only 10 times after which he should be directed to payment page. I can use sessions on the search results page, but how can i put a counter on that. Can any please help me on that.

Answer (score 4):

Every time a search request is created you just do

```
$_SESSION['counter']++
```

Altough he can just get rid of the limit by deleting cookies. An other approach would be, to store the number of search requests in a database table including the IP address, but this can also be bypassed, while it takes more work to do so.

Answer (score 4):

If you should put search limit on current running session than you can use `$_SESSION['count']++`.
And if you should put search limit per day than you can use `'UPDATE users SET search_count = search_count+1'`

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you would allow him to search again when he comes to your website or just those 10 times even after he visits after a year.

For temporary bases, you can use cookies (see `setcookie` function) but if you want to restrict him once and for all, you will have to ssave that information in database.

You would code something like:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
  // more logic/code
```

Now you will have to save the value of `$_SESSION['counter']`.

Answer (score 2):

If your users can search only while logged in, then I see no problem - you definitely have db table with users, so just add another column to it, say 'search_count' and increase it by one each time user attemps a search.

For example:

```
UPDATE `users` SET search_count = search_count+1
```

Comment: As he said, it's for guests, which I assume don't have a login.

Comment: @Ahatius: Didn't noticed that. As for guest, good answers are given, but anyway - cookies can be erased and sessions do expire.

Comment: It does not have a login, but the user has to enter his email address to go on that page, through which I think i can store the search counts in the database through email as well as IP.

Comment: Then this suites very good for you. But consider, that users can always use fake emails and this limitation will be effortless

Comment: hmm.. you are right, so if i take both email as IP address as unique values, I think I can still control fake users. But one more issue is if any one use proxies to make multiple accounts

Comment: Another problem is if more than one user will use same IP. For example, your product is very intresting for some kind of company. If you limit search for IP, the whole office won't be able to search, no matter of the email.

Comment: Well, to bypass that problem with several persons using the same IP you'll have to use an IP email combination, where only 1 combination of IP and email is allowed. It's always hard identifying users which don't have a login.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a counter in the table user of your db and call a function everytime the user looks for the result, that increments the value by one, so a simple UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I think maintaining database will be much better then maintaining SESSION because may be due to some reason session removed or erased.

add a field within `users` table name for example `visit` with `default value 0` and update this field on every visit of search result page..

```
 "update usertablename set visitfield = visitfield + 1 where user_id = ".$current_user_id
```

thanks

Comment: A guest doesn't have an user id

Comment: If user not logged in then user has to maintain a cookie or session on based on browser and increment that on each visit . and that session or cookie must be removed on browser close.